# Article loads in same position the link is and not the whole page

Tags: joomla

I'm using Joomla 3.7

I have a link in the home page that redirects to an article. But when i click it, it redirects to same home page and the article loads in the position where the link is. I noticed that this is happening when the article doesn't have a menu item.

Any idea how to solve this?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Same thing is happening again using DJ-Image Slider. Now using the solution below doesn't work.

-

I got the solution to my answer.

It was a problem of href property on a tag.

In order to redirect to an article, i'm using the Article Button located at the TinyMCE Joomla Editor.

I just entered into code editor, and changed this:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" style="border-radius: 10px;" href="index.php?option=com_content&amp;view=article&amp;id=19&amp;catid=2">Asociarse</a>
```

To this:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" style="border-radius: 10px;" href="?option=com_content&amp;view=article&amp;id=19&amp;catid=2">Asociarse</a>
```

And it worked.